# Kinetic equations

Tags: artificial-satellite

The kinetic equation of rotational motion of a satellite using Newton’s law can be expressed as follows:
$$
\frac{\partial H_b}{\partial t}+\omega_b\times H_b=T_d   \qquad(1) 
$$
In the above relation $T_d$  is the disturbance torque applied to the
satellite, $H_b$ is the angular momentum vector expressed in
the body coordinate system and $ω_b$ is the angular velocity of the
Body Coordinate System relative to the Inertial Coordinate System that is expressed in the Body Coordinate System. For a satellite with three
reaction wheels, $H_b$ can be obtained from the angular momentum of the satellite and reaction wheels as follows:
$$
H_b=J\omega_b+J_{w1}\omega_{w1}+J_{w2}\omega_{w2}+J_{w3}\omega_{w3} \qquad(2)
$$
J is Moment of Inertia Matrix. $\omega_{wi}$ is the angular velocity of the $i$th wheel relative to the Body Coordinate System.

My question is how is equation (2) obtained.

Comment: What is the source of the equations you quote?

Comment: The article I quoted from: Quaternion based linear time-varying model predictive attitude control for satellites with two reaction wheels

Comment: Do you have a link to the article?

Comment: Note that the terms in the second equation are all vectors.

Comment: @Organic Marble, link to the article is: https://af.booksc.eu/book/80755351/1c6738

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equation 2 is just applying the definition.  For any object, angular momentum is moment of inertia tensor times angular velocity vector.  Equation 2 says there are four spinning things, and this is how their contributions to the total angular momentum are named in this paper.